# AngularJS custom filter within directive to format value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a directive that formats the provided value that it renders, and for this formatting logic to be part of that directive, not dependent on a HTML attribute or parent controller.

My simplified attempt with a single attribute and tag looks like this, but gives a `TypeError: definition.match is not a function` error.

```
app.directive('timeSpan', function() {
  scope: {
    value: '@value',
    displayValue: function(v) {
      return v / 1000.0;
    },
    displayUnits: function(v) {
      return 'seconds';
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<span>{{value|displayValue}} {{value|displayUnits}}</span>'
  }
}

<time-span value="{{timer}}" />
```

Comment: it's because filter aren't simple function, they should be defined in a special way, check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to create a controller for your directive and declare your `displayUnits` and `displayValue` functions inside that controller.

```
.directive('timeSpan', function() {
  return {
      scope: {
        value: '@value'
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<span>{{displayValue(value)}} {{displayUnits(value)}}</span>',
      controller: 'TimeSpanCtrl',
  };
})
.controller('TimeSpanCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.displayValue = function(v) {
      return v / 1000.0;
    };

    $scope.displayUnits = function(v) {
      return 'seconds';
    }
}]);
```

Similar question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631034/typeerror-i-match-is-not-a-function)